# how to write a DSL without imports or val using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dsl

I'm trying to create a kotlin DSl following the example here https://github.com/zsmb13/VillageDSL

They write :

```
val v = village {
    house {
        person {
            name = "Emily"
            age = 31
        }
        person(name = "Hannah") {
            age = 27
        }
        person("Alex", 21)
        person(age = 17, name = "Daniel")
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is way to write it like with gradle, like this :

```
village {
    house {
        person {
            name = "Emily"
            age = 31
        }
        person(name = "Hannah") {
            age = 27
        }
        person("Alex", 21)
        person(age = 17, name = "Daniel")
    }
}
```

And autogenerate imports (like in gradle).

I was thinking to wrap the file programmatically with a wildcard import followed by `val result =`, but it could be leaky and buggy, is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider Kotlin Scripting for that. e.g. https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md
or 
https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript